# How is this even possible? Accessing object variables

Tags: javascript, variables, object

How is this even possible? I thought in first two examples it should return undefined.

```
function SecretCode() {
    var _secretNum = 78;

    this.guessNum = function(num) {
        if(num > _secretNum) {
            return console.log("Lower"); 
        } else if (num < _secretNum) {
            return console.log("Higher");
        } else {
            return console.log("You guessed it");
        } 
    }
}

let secret = new SecretCode();
secret.guessNum(this.secretNum);    //You guessed it
secret.guessNum(this._secretNum);   //You guessed it
secret.guessNum(secretNum);         //is not defined
secret.guessNum(_secretNum);        //is not defined
console.log(secret.secretNum);      //undefined
console.log(secret._secretNum);     //undefined
```

Comment: You are running your functions in the context of `window`, so `this` refers to `window`, NOT `secret`

Comment: `this` in the call `secret.guessNum(this.secretNum)` refers to `window`, and window has no `secretNum` so it's undefined and the first two conditions will not satisfy, and the else statement runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as arguments of the function call, `this.secretNum` and `this._secretNum` are both undefined. But both `num > undefined` and  `num < undefined` return false. So the `if` structure has no other possibility than to get on the 3rd branch.

Comment: It should be noted that this could have been figured out by just checking what happens if you try to compare against `undefined`.

Comment: Oh man I just realised how stupid my question was. Thanks a lot to everybody answering this question!

Answer (score 0):

First two examples write out "You guessed it" because `this.secretNum` resolves to `undefined` and so `num` argument resolves to `undefined` and so neither `(num > _secretNum)` nor `(num < _secretNum)` is true. The same is of course true for `this._secretNum`;

Comment: I didn't notice it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments against each line.Hope this will be useful

```
    //Initiating a constructor function
    let secret = new SecretCode();
    // here this refers to window object/ In window there is no secretNum
    // So in all if clause will fail since undefined is never greater than the 
    number
    secret.guessNum(this.secretNum); //You guessed it
   // Same reason as of above.
    secret.guessNum(this._secretNum); //You guessed it
    // In below case you are trying to pass an argument which is no where 
    defined
    // So it is showing not defined
    secret.guessNum(secretNum); //is not defined
    secret.guessNum(_secretNum); //is not defined
    // In this two case you are trying to pass value from constructor function 
    but that is also not defined, & the function is also not returning it

    console.log(secret.secretNum); //undefined
    console.log(secret._secretNum); //undefined
```